# How to get the name of decorator for function at run time?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

In the following code the methods(`print_a` and `print_b`) of class `Test`, has been decorated by the two different decorators.

How can I determine that the given method(let say `print_a`), is decorated with some specific decorator (`decorator1`) at the runtime?

The easy solution is to change the name of the wrapper function, i.e. changing the `wrapper` to `wrapper1` and `wrapper2` in the decorator method, but the problem with that is I don't have control over that part of the code.

Does python have any reflection API like Java, and could that help me here ?

```
def my_decorator1(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('I am decorated:1')
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def my_decorator2(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('I am decorated:2')
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Test():

    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @my_decorator1
    def print_a(self):
        print('Value of a is {}'.format(self.a))

    @my_decorator2
    def print_b(self):
        print('Value of b is {}'.format(self.b))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    d = Test.__dict__

    f1 = d.get('print_a')
    f2 = d.get('print_b')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python decorators are more about transforming functions than about acting as simple metadata labels, as one often does with Java annotations. So to do this, I'd have the decorator set a property on the function it is wrapping (or perhaps wrap it in a callable of a particular type):

```
def my_decorator1(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('I am decorated:1')
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.decorator_name = 'my_decorator1'
    return wrapper
```

Then:

```
print(Test.print_a.decorator_name)
```

Alternatively, in Python 3.3+ you can use PEP 3155's `__qualname__` to identify the decorator.

Comment: The OP said he had no access to the decorator definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Since the decorator function is executed at decoration time, it is difficult to get the name. You can solve your problem with an additional decorator. The decorator `annotator` writes into a property of the function and you can read this name inside of the decorated function:

```
def annotator(decorator):
    def wrapper(f):
        g = decorator(f)
        g.decorator = decorator.__name__
        return g
    return wrapper

@annotator(my_decorator1)
def x():
    print x.decorator
```

Comment: I have no access to decorator code but I think I need to request the maintainer to add this.

Comment: If you adapt my example this shouldn't be necessary, and it will work for decorators where you can't request the maintainer.

Comment: gotcha, this is new decorator which is calling actual decorator